# Drag-and-drop to a non-view

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to go about dragging a file to a small target. What I really need is the files metadata. I don't need to display the file itself, only it's contents(these are custom files that are more like directories). I have seen examples for dragging to an NSView but what I think I need is an example of dragging to a simple, small textView in my NSObject class. Then I need to get the files contents so I can parse it.

Does Cocoa require that all drag and drop be done via Views? 
Any Help very much appreciated

So to add to what I posted earlier;
I followed the example at http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/072-NSView-drag-and-drop.pl for drag and drop images. It works great for both browsers and the Finder for images, but it will not work for other file types.

appended 10/4/2011
As stated above, I followed the drag and drop example at the link above for dropping TIFF based images. It works as it should for dragging images into a custom view both from the web or from the Finder. What I don't understand is what I need to do to get it to work for simple text files and even more importantly, custom files. I have read the drag and drop information on the Mac Dev site but still don't understand it enough to make the necessary modifications.

Here is my code:

```
//myNSView.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyNSView : NSView
{
    NSImage *nsImageObj;

}
@property(assign) NSImage *nsImageObj;

-(IBAction)reset:(id)sender;

@end



//myNSV.m


#import "MyNSView.h"

@implementation MyNSView
@synthesize nsImageObj;

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    if(!(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: MyNSView initWithFrame");
        return self;
    }//end if
    self.nsImageObj = nil;

    [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSTIFFPboardType, NSFilenamesPboardType, nil]];
    return self;
}//end initWithFrame

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    if(self.nsImageObj == nil){
        [[NSColor blackColor]set];
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
    }//end if

    NSRect zOurBounds = [self bounds];
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    [self.nsImageObj compositeToPoint:(zOurBounds.origin) operation:NSCompositeSourceOver];
}
-(IBAction)reset:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"reset Button Pressed");
    nsImageObj = nil;
   NSLog(@"check Image %@", self.nsImageObj);
    [[NSColor blackColor]set];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

-(NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender{

    //is the sender looking for NSDragOperationGeneric
    if((NSDragOperationGeneric & [sender draggingSourceOperationMask]) == NSDragOperationGeneric)
        return NSDragOperationGeneric;
    else
        return NSDragOperationNone;

}//end draggingEntered


-(BOOL) prepareForDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    return YES;
}// end prepareForDragOperation

-(BOOL)performDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
   //initialize pasteboard
    NSPasteboard *zPasteboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    //initialize image file types, addedd some extra
    NSArray *zImageTypesArray =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSPasteboardTypeTIFF,NSFilenamesPboardType, nil];

    NSString *zDesiredType = [zPasteboard availableTypeFromArray: zImageTypesArray];

            if([zDesiredType isEqualToString:NSPasteboardTypeTIFF]){

                NSData *zPasteboardData = [zPasteboard dataForType:zDesiredType];

                //make sure we have data
                if(zPasteboardData == nil){
                    NSLog(@"Error: MyNsView zPasteBoardData == nil");
                    return NO;
                }//end if nil

                self.nsImageObj = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData: zPasteboardData];
                [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

                return YES;

            }//end outer if
            //if desired types is a string of filenames
    if([zDesiredType isEqualToString:NSFilenamesPboardType]){
        NSArray *zFileNamesAry = [zPasteboard propertyListForType:@"NSFilenamesPboardType"];
        NSString *zPath = [zFileNamesAry objectAtIndex:0];

        NSImage *zNewImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:zPath];

                if(zNewImage == nil){

                    NSLog(@"Error: MyNSView performDragOperation zNewImage = nil");
                    return NO;
                }

                //else everything is good in here

        self.nsImageObj = zNewImage;
        [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        return YES;

    }//end outer if

    //if we get here than there was an unknown error return no
    NSLog(@"Error Unknown in MYNSView performDragOperation");
    return NO;
}

-(void)concludeDragOperation:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)sender{

    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];

}

@end
```

I am hoping some one can point out what I need to learn to get this figured out. Maybe its my confusion with Pasteboards, maybe its another component I'm not even aware of yet. As always, I really appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: If there's something on screen for the drop to be performed on, then that will be an NSView surely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, an NSTextView is a subclass of NSView (distantly). Second, to *receive* drop events, yes, you really do need a view. Third, what you're having trouble with is the type of information on the dragging pasteboard.

Set up a view and register for NSFilenamesPboardType as described in the [Drag and Drop Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001288-CEGJFDFG) guide. When you get your file names, use [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or use the Spotlight metadata API to get whatever information about the file that you need.

Comment: Can you recommend a link that would show the steps for creating a drag and drop drop zone for a variety of files?  I have seen a few tutorials on the web for drag and drop images. I did the one at

Comment: The one I gave you explains this. What have you tried and what isn't working about it?

Comment: When ever I try to drag and drop a text file, nothing happens. if the if([zDesiredType isEqualToString:NSPasteboardTypeTIFF]) then it works , but if the Pasteboard does not contain that string, it is null. It should have a string array of filenames with the txt file name in it (NSFilenamesPboardType)as I understand it.

Comment: @Miek: Wild stab in the dark: You forgot to register the view for drags. We can only provide more information or a more relevant solution if you provide more information about the problem, including all of your drag-related code. (Please edit that into your question—it won't fit in a comment.)

Comment: I appended my post so it is complete. Please take another look. Thanks

Comment: Do you create your view programmatically (calling -initWithFrame:)? If not, you'll need to do so in the view's -awakeFromNib method.

Comment: I think I'm making small progress in my understanding;I think NSFileNamesPboardType is the correct board. debugging shows the path to txt file is being read. NSIamge is going to be nill for a txt file. Its not made to read one. I need to use NSString I Think for this case.